Tears and fasting
When we yawn or sneeze our eyes will tear up. The tears will then drain away into the nasal cavity and to the throat via the tear ducts. Does this invalidate fasting? This is considering that having enough sleep is within one's control. And if he intentionally stays up late he would repeatedly yawn during the day.

It doesn't invalidate the fasting.
